# Django, Product matching query does not exist

Tags: django

### Product matching query does not exist.

### views.py

```
def single(request, slug):
     product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)~ this line of code is running errors    

    context = {
    "product": product,    
    }
    return render_to_response("products/single.html",context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### urls.py

```
    url(r'^$', 'profiles.views.landing', name="landing"),
    url(r'^all/$', 'products.views.all', name="all_products"),
    url(r'^products/(?P<slug>.*)/$', 'products.views.single', name="single_product")
    the slug is not working properly, I'm not sure why.
```

Comment: What error are you getting? If you get a `Product.DoesNotExist` error, try logging the `slug` and see if it exists in the Product database.

Comment: For your use case, it is better if you call `get_or_404` instead of `get` (it has the same signature), so the error is transformed into a 404 response (resource not found for the specified url)

Comment: product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)#changed the variable from products to product to get single product.

Comment: The error you got was a variable-name-related issue? What was the exception you were getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
url(r'^products/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$', 'products.views.single', name="single_product")
```

`.*` means "is not required".

Also I recommend you to take a look at [DetaiView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) which can handle 404 and stuff

```
class ProductView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'products/single.html'
    context_object_name = 'product'

single = ProductView.as_view()
```

That's it!

Comment: `.*` **does not mean** "is not required". `.*` means "any -greedy- set of characters"

Comment: Oh, sorry for my English, didn't know how to say: "slug could be an empty string", so function will handle 'products//' and 'products/slug/' as well. In my language it' just "not required" :)

Comment: Oh :$ its ok :p. althought you're not so far from the meaning you wanted to achieve. The difference between `.*` and `.+` is that `.*` is not required, while `.+` expects at least one character. The fact is not the term "not-required", but that `.*` means more that just no-required (and could even match a slash, which may not be an expected behavior, depending on the case - e.g. it could match `/products/pija/gorda/` as well)

Comment: Your case in the solution is the most common and accepted, since slugs are not expected to be "any -freely- character", but restrict themselves to the character set you're using: the base-64 ones.

Answer (score 0):

Regex should be like this: `(?P<slug>\w+)` (I assume that in model it is charfield).

Your regex gives two matches instead of one, the second match is empty.

After that make sure that object with that slug exists in database.